# PGError: ERROR: relation "delayed_jobs" does not exist (Postgresql, rails 3.04, delayed_job error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I did `rake db:create` and then `rake db:migrate` and ran into this error.

```
rake aborted!
PGError: ERROR:  relation "delayed_jobs" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"delayed_jobs"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"delayed_jobs"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your query is casting "delayed_jobs" to a regclass, which translates the name of a table to PostgreSQL's internal ID number. If the cast can't be made you get the error:
  SELECT 'foo'::regclass;
  ERROR:  relation "foo" does not exist

Presumably your migrate script should be catching this error and creating the table (maybe the problem is it already thinks it has done so).

P.S. - The title of your question isn't helpful. PostgreSQL doesn't have a problem working with "delayed_job". Not only don't you have a table "delayed_job" but the problem is clearly with Rail's create or migrate scripts.

Comment: Think you're right, I manually inserted the table and it works. Changed the title as per request.

Comment: I am having this same problem. Can you explain how you inserted the table manually?

Answer (score 0):

rake db:migrate:redo STEP=88
88 is a number larger than all your talbes