# Moving a working Rails app, cannot load schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895904/pgerror-error-relation-delayed-jobs-does-not-exist-postgreqsql-rails-3-04) seems relevant to the error below, but I do not know how to create this troublesome 'categories' table manually. Could anyone spell out how to do what that answerer proposes?

```
.../current$ bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load
rake aborted!
PGError: ERROR:  relation "categories" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"categories"'::regclass
                                        ^
:                 SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"categories"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Comment: You can create table manually in psql console: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `rake db:migrate`. Maybe the schema is not updated.

Comment: The schema is definitely not updated; I am working with a fresh database. But ``db:migrate`` generates the same error.